# Why was this happening at the end of Sandman volume 4?

Tags: comics, the-sandman, vertigo-comics

At the end of *The Sandman vol. 4: Season of Mists*, we see

> Duma and Remiel are now the rulers of hell.

I can't remember which one of two, but one of them suddenly flies up and we see the other one chained and is being punished by a demon.

What did he do that he was being punished for it?

Answer (score 5):

You are most certainly remembering something wrong.

Remiel flies up, yes, but it is not Duma, nor any other angel that he encounters. He goes to see just a random doomed soul.

You are probably referring to those three panels (click for full resolution):

[image] [image] [image]

Duma is the Angel of Silence. Thus the flying angel is not Duma, but Remiel. The tortured soul is also not Duma, because he talks.

Duma remains in the tower, while Remiel flies around, naively proclaiming that the souls are now being punished to be redeemed.

For further exploration of the inner workings of Hell, refer to the story arcs "A Dalliance with the Damned" and "Inferno" of Mike Carey's *Lucifer*,
 issues #17-19, and #29-32, respectively.

Comment: @Radhil Is Geometry not Divine already, my friend? (I actually had a teacher that pronounced "angle" like "angel")

Comment: Heh.   I'm still waking up, so I'm sure I can find a fractal that I can stare at until it turns into angels.  Or an Escher.  (I also had one math teacher with an outrageous accent, I vaguely remember frac-ti-ons being said like every vowel was an independent state).

Answer (score 3):

No Angel was being tortured.

Duma, the Angel of Silence, just shouldered the burden of the key and went on being silent.  He can be seen reclining in almost every scene he's in afterwards. Remiel is the one who can't stand this fate, and flies out to oversee Hell, and make the proclamation that the punishments are now being done with "love" and rehabilitation in mind.

What you see in those frames responding to Remiel is just another damned soul being serviced by the demons, not the Angel Duma.

Comment: There should have been a disclaimer. "No angel was hurt during the making of this comic" :-)